# Upgrading XAMPP, mysql tables "lost"

Tags: mysql, upgrade, xampp

To upgrade from my older XAMPP to a newer one, I renamed the folder `C:\XAMPP` to `C:\XAMPP_OLD` and installed the newer version with `xampp-win32-5.6.8-0-VC11-installer.exe` into `C:\XAMPP`. Then I ran `setup_xampp.bat`, renamed the MySQL user `root` to `cubinator`, gave this user a password and changed the following lines in `config.inc.php` from

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'cubinator';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '...';
```

After that, I copied my old database folders into `C:\XAMPP\mysql\data`. To test, if everything is working so far, I started the MySQL server via the XAMPP control. In the command prompt I typed in the following:

```
C:\XAMPP\mysql\bin>mysql -u cubinator -p
Enter password: ********
mysql>use my_db
Database changed
mysql>show tables;
... (List of my tables. Everything fine so far) ...
mysql>select * from one_of_my_tables;
ERROR 1146 (42502): Table 'my_db.one_of_my_tables' doesn't exist.
```

This also happens in *phpMyAdmin*: I clicked on `my_db`, so I can see a list of my tables. But these tables don't exist, when clicking on them. I checked my `data` directory, but all `.frm` and `.ibd` files exist and are not empty.

**Do I have to register my tables somewhere?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the data folder from one MySQL installation to another (which is unreliable), why not use something like [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)?

Example of usage:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > mydb.sql
```

And then to import in the new database:

```
mysql < mydb.sql
```

Comment: Thank you :) It worked with `mysqldump -u cubinator -p --databases my_first_db my_second_db > my_dump_file.sql` and `mysql -u cubinator -p < my_dump_file.sql` with shutting down the old server and starting the new server between these two commands.